# decrypt and encrypt a file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, encryption

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a file using the code below.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382044(v=vs.85).aspx
The encryption link has been given to this link only.
When I am trying to decrypt a file. That has been encrypted using the link given. It is only decrypting one block of data not complete file.
If I change the dwBlockLen = 1000000 - 1000000 % ENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE; then it works but still one block at a time.

I need to make it work inside do while statement given in the code. So that it reads on block of data at once and decrypt it.

Comment: So what's stopping you? That sounds like a *problem*, not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing value of `dwBlockLen` is NOT required (will not solve the issue). Value of `dwBlockLen` determines amount of data read **at a time**. While loop is present to read the complete source file. The condition to exit the while loop is :

```
 if(Amount of data read from file < dwBlockLen)
```

Which means there is NO more data to be read and loop exits.

You must debug the condition `if(dwCount <= dwBlockLen)' in code below, most likely there is issue while reading the source file.

```
   // Decrypt the source file, and write to the destination file. 
    bool fEOF = false;
    do
    {
        //-----------------------------------------------------------
        // Read up to dwBlockLen bytes from the source file. 
        // ...
        if(dwCount <= dwBlockLen)
        {
            fEOF = TRUE;
        }

        //-----------------------------------------------------------
        // Decrypt the block of data. 
        // ...
        //-----------------------------------------------------------
        // Write the decrypted data to the destination file. 
        // ...
        //-----------------------------------------------------------
        // End the do loop when the last block of the source file 
        // has been read, encrypted, and written to the destination 
        // file.
    }while(!fEOF);
```

Comment: Need to check for the condition if(dwCount == dwBlockLen) else make it false so that crydecrypt function will come to know this is the last block to decrypt